# what is the equivalent of IP_TOS (PPROTO_IP option in setsockopt function for IPv4 socket) in IPv6 addressing?

Tags: sockets

I am using `setsocketopt` function for Ipv4 address and using  `IP_TOS` value for `PPROTO_IP` option.

what is the equivalent of IP_TOS in IPv6 addressing? 
In IPv6 we use `PROTO_IPv6`, but I could not find any equivalent option like `IP_TOS` in IPv6 addressing.

Comment: Remember ToS has been obsoleted with [DSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services) in IPv4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MSDN Article ID: 248611](http://web.archive.org/web/20190119192230/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248611/setsockopt-is-unable-to-mark-the-internet-protocol-type-of-service-bit) ToS is ignored and the GQOS API is limited to IPv4-only.  For IPv6 and IPv4 you must use [qWAVE QOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb960848%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which requires Vista or later platforms.

i.e. QoS is completely abstracted away from BSD sockets in Windows land.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how widely supported it is, but I believe the constant for "setsockopt() traffic class" would be `IPV6_TCLASS`:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3542.txt

See also:

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.commtechref/doc/commtrf2/setsockopt.htm
- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am working in Window Environment. IPv6_TCLASS is an option in Linux Libraries.

Comment: IPv6_TCLASS is not present in the Windows Socket Libraries I am using. I am using VS2008 environment.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know how widely supported IPV6_TCLASS is - it varies from platform to platform.  As others also said, the old IPv4 "IP_TOS" is obsolete.  So: 1) if you want to know the IPV6 equivalent of "setsockopt(), IP_TOS", the answer is "IPV6_TCLASS". 2) But be aware [Comparison of IPv4 vs IPv6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzai2%2Frzai2compipv4ipv6.htm): "IP_TOS: Designates the IPv6 traffic class, similarly to IPv4. Uses different codes. Currently, IPv6 does not support TOS."

Answer (score 0):

[Deprecating old QoS APIs](http://web.archive.org/web/20151208005603/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/07/05/657196.aspx)

"Back in XP we had disabled the Winsock IP_TOS option. If you used this socket option, the call would succeed but be ignored silently. You could re-enable it through a registry value. In Vista, this registry mechanism has been removed: **Winsock IP_TOS option is no longer available.**"